# PostgreSQL seems to ignore RAISE EXCEPTION in a CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte

Using PostgreSQL 9.3 I have been trying to define an `assert` helper function to check for empty query results and similar things as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.assert (
    in_assertion boolean,
    in_errormessage text
)
RETURNS boolean
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY INVOKER
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT in_assertion THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'assertion failed: %', in_errormessage;
        END IF;

        RETURN in_assertion;
    END;
$function$
;
```

Upon testing I found that the exception is not thrown as I would expect. For example, with `CREATE TABLE emptytable (somecolumn text);` and

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.testassert_buggy (
    out somevalue text
)
LANGUAGE sql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
    WITH firstquery AS (
            SELECT * FROM emptytable
    ), nonemptycheck AS (
            SELECT assert(count(*) = 42, 'nonemptycheck failed') FROM firstquery
    ) SELECT * FROM firstquery;
$function$
;
```

I would expect a call like `SELECT testassert_buggy();` to throw the exception, but instead the result is

```
 somevalue 
-----------

(1 row)
```

(Note that `firstquery` actually returns 0 rows; the 1 row is due to this being a function with `out` parameters.)

With the following small change in the second-to-last line, the exception IS thrown.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.testassert (
    out somevalue text
)
LANGUAGE sql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
    WITH firstquery AS (
            SELECT * FROM emptytable
    ), nonemptycheck AS (
            SELECT assert(count(*) = 42, 'nonemptycheck failed') FROM firstquery
    ) SELECT firstquery.* FROM nonemptycheck, firstquery;
$function$
;
```

If I rewrite the last query switching the table list (i.e. with `FROM firstquery, nonemptycheck`) there is again no exception. I'm puzzled. Is the query optimized in some way that ignores side-effects like exceptions? I tried to remove `IMMUTABLE` from the definition of `assert`, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Unreferenced CTEs are not executed at all** - [except data-modifying CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810159/939860).

[Related thread on pgsql-bugs with Tom Lane explaining the behavior.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5673.1335391361@sss.pgh.pa.us)

In your first example you have:

```
SELECT * FROM firstquery;
```

No reference to the CTE `nonemptycheck`. So the CTE is never executed.

In the second example you have:

```
SELECT firstquery.* FROM nonemptycheck, firstquery;
```

`nonemptycheck` is referenced, so it is executed, resulting in the exception.

#### No row

Your added test case in the comment fails for a similar reason. Since the first CTE returns ***no row***, the outer SELECT returns *no row*. There is no need to execute the second CTE, since the result will not be displayed. The optimizer's job is to avoid fruitless work ..

Appending `nonemptycheck` as cross-joined subquery (`CROSS JOIN` or appended after comma) instead of a second CTE **does *not* help, either**. A **similar optimization** avoids execution: Since `firstquery` returns no row, there is no point in evaluating the `nonemptycheck`, even in a subquery:

```
WITH firstquery AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   emptytable
   WHERE  FALSE
   )
SELECT f.*     -- even if you append ", n.*" to SELECT list
FROM   firstquery f
    , (
   SELECT assert(count(*) = 42, 'check failed')
   FROM   firstquery
   ) n;         -- not executed
```

#### Solution

You can force evaluation with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
WITH firstquery AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   emptytable
   WHERE  false
   )
SELECT f.*
FROM   firstquery f
FULL   JOIN (
   SELECT assert(count(*) = 42, 'check failed')
   FROM   firstquery
   ) nonemptycheck ON true;  -- always executed
```

Side effect: This would return a single row filled with `NULL` values, when `firstquery` returns no row. Not in this particular case, though, since your assert raises an exception in this case.

Comment: Thanks Erwin; this seems to be part of the issue, but other optimizations seem to play a role as well; for example, in

 `WITH firstquery AS (SELECT *  FROM emptytable WHERE false), nonemptycheck AS (SELECT assert(count(*) = 42, 'check failed') FROM firstquery) SELECT * FROM firstquery, nonemptycheck;`

the exception is not thrown, even though the outer SELECT references the inner ones. EXPLAIN ANALYZE says "never executed" for nonemptycheck. With all that in mind, is there a way to define a robust assert function?

Comment: @ChrisM.: That's a ***second excellent question***, hidden in a comment. I suggest you edit it into your question, this might become a "go-to" question to reference in the future. I added a possible solution.