# Insert into multiple tables with one query

Tags: postgresql, cte

I would like to add data to at least three tables with one query. I thought of something like this:

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO core.adr
    (street, "number", postal_code, city)
  VALUES
    ('test 1', '25a', '00912', 'villageman')
  RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO core.adr_information
  (idref, info)
SELECT id, 'test data'
FROM ins;
```

which works perfectly for exactly two tables.

Main problem here is, that all additional queries require the `id` value from the first `INSERT` query, which seems not manageable this way. I think it could be easily done with a stored procedure or transaction, but I would like the solution to be a simple and solid query.

Am I overlooking something? Is it possible that way or another (no stored procedures* or transactions)?

---

**Note**

<sub>* Altough, strictly speaking, Postgres does not *have* stored procedures, only functions, as [@Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684) rightly pointed out via comments. See [this series of posts for relevant information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684).</sub>

Comment: other way - trigger on one table with insert into any number of other

Comment: What makes it seem `not manageable this way`? Because it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can easily pile the CTEs on top of each other, like so:

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO core.adr
    (street, "number", postal_code, city)
  VALUES
    ('test 1', '25a', '00912', 'villageman')
  RETURNING id),
ins2 AS (
  INSERT INTO someothertable
    (id, something)
  SELECT id, 'something' FROM ins
  RETURNING id -- this is necessary for CTE, but not used
)
INSERT INTO core.adr_information
  (idref, info)
SELECT id, 'test data'
FROM ins;
```

Comment: Correct. Except, the 2nd `RETURNING` is not necessary. Data-modifying CTEs are always executed to completion either way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810159/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I guess that's true if you don't explicitly specify CTE columns.

Comment: What do you mean by `explicitly specify CTE columns`? Test your code without the 2nd `RETURNING` and you'll see that it works. Consider the quotes from the manual in the related answer I linked.

Comment: `with cte ( col1 ) as (select ...)` explicitly specifies a column (`col1`) in which case you'll need `returning`.

Comment: That's correct, of course. You wouldn't declare columns to be returned if you are not going to return columns ... Nitpicking: Your example in the comment uses `select`, where this does ***not*** apply. On the contrary: Basic CTEs (not *data-modifying*) which are not referenced by other CTEs or the outer statement are *never executed*! http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69650/3684

Comment: @mustaccio thanks, that works fine for me.

Comment: How do you do this when inserting multiple rows? Are there any performance advantages over storing returning ids in an array, then do another insertion using the ids?  Thanks